# How to set content-type header as JSON in controller Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, controllers, json, json-response

I am having the controller which is responding with resultJson(\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory), I have given setData. And I need to set header as JSON. I want the JSON result in the tree(PRETTY) format. Kindly help me.

This is my code:

```
\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
.
.
$resultJson = $this->_resultJsonFactory->create();
.
.
$resultJson->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json',true);
$resultJson->setData(["view_url"=> "/","results"=>$results]);

return $resultJson;
```

which is resulting with:

```
{"view_url":"\/","results":[{"product_image":"\/p11.jpg","product_name":"name1","product_desc":"protection.","absorbency":"hik","special_size":"Yes","product_url":"\/"},{"product_image":"\/p1.jpg","product_name":"name2","product_desc":" protection.","absorbency":"high","special_size":"No","product_url":"\/"}]}
```

But i need like this: (with response header as JSON)

```
{
  "view_url": "/",
  "results": [
    {
      "product_image": "/p11.jpg",
      "product_name": "name1",
      "product_desc": "protection.",
      "absorbency": "hik",
      "special_size": "Yes",
      "product_url": "/"
    },
    {
      "product_image": "/p1.jpg",
      "product_name": "name2",
      "product_desc": " protection.",
      "absorbency": "high",
      "special_size": "No",
      "product_url": "/"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please more clarify what is your current result and what is your expected.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your JSON response I don't see any issue. Validated [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

I don't think you will see any issue in decoding this response if you wanna read it further because format is valid.

If you wanna see it beautiful in your browser then you can use browser extension. I use Chrome Extension JSONView. Check [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?hl=en).

Hope this is helpful. Cheers!